Rename Related List between 2 objects which has a Standard Master Detail relation

How to rename the highlighted one, dynamic list - single.
There's a lookup relationship created between individual and Account.

Relationship between them is Master-Detail where Contact Point are child and Individual is the parent.
Even if we create a custom field and rename the Related List Label it will still show up with the standard one.


First Guess: Go to the lookup field on the child object and edit the "Related List Label"

Have you searched the documentation?

Should have given more details regarding it. Have updated the question. Also i did go through the documentation, but the relationship between is a standard one where Contact Point ones are child and individual is the parent. How do i edit that. What's the work around that.
